# Nested Dictionaries in .json file | Problem with iteration

Tags: python, json

For some reason the method B(as shown below in the code block) does not work. No errors... it just never passes the third `if` statement.
Please mind the double `==`, for `messageID` argument, since I need the string type

```py
@command(name="test")
async def rr(self, ctx, messageID: Optional[int], group: str, *, title: Optional[str] = "No title Provided."):

    with open('./path_to_file/test.json', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        groupIDs = data['RRGroups']
        msgIDs = data['msgIDs']

        #working
        if group in groupIDs:
            groupEntry = groupIDs[group]
            print(groupEntry)

        #method A - Working
        messageID == (msgIDs['msgID'] for msgID in msgIDs if messageID in msgIDs.keys())
        if messageID:
            print("msg found A")
            print(messageID)

        #method B - not working
        if messageID in msgIDs: #also tried with msgIDs.keys()
            print("msg found B")
            msgID == msgIDs[messageID]
            print(msgID)
```

json file structure :

```json
{
   "RRGroups":{
      "groupA":{
         "keyA1":"valueA1",
         "keyA2":"valueA2"
      },
      "groupB":{
         "keyB1":"valueB1",
         "keyB2":"valueB2"
      },
      "groupC":{
         "keyC1":"valueC1",
         "keyC2":"valueC2"
      }
   },
   "msgIDs":{
      "838493938373099531":"832636716380586015",
      "836977954025504819":"832636716380586015",
      "836977964402999326":"832636716380586015"
   }
}
```

Comment: The expression `(a for b in c)` is a generator expression, and evaluates to `True` in `if`, regardless of whether it's empty or not. The `for`-loop in it is not executed in your case.

Comment: *"it just never passes the if statement"* Please be more accurate, there are three `if` statements.

Comment: I either misinterpreting your answer or you missed the comment above Method A(the one that does contain a `for` loop). Method A is working fine and prints the msgID string successfully.
The problem is with my Method B where I tried to use the same logic a groupID.

Comment: @KlausD. fixed the initial message. The third `if` statement. First and Second ones are working fine

Comment: @Taraxiah the "method A" only seems to work. Try replacing `if messageID` with `if list(messageID)` and you'll see why.

Comment: @bereal tried both `if (list(messageID) in msgIDs)` and `if list(messageID) in msgIDs` and I am getting `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: @Taraxiah I mean, replacing it in the condition that precedes `print`, not in the loop.

Comment: @bereal I don't follow. I did try what you suggested in both 2nd(not inside the loop) and 3rd `if` statement, and I am getting the same error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: @Taraxiah please provide a [mcve] including the data, I cannot test it otherwise.

Comment: @bereal this a Cog(extension) for a discord bot so in order to reproduce it you need a working bot.
IF you have one, you can just copy paste the whole `Cog` code from the following link : https://mystb.in/BasenameBuckSpectrum.python . And of course create a json file and update the path.
I cannot think of an alternative way for you to test it, sorry :(